# Optimizing - formatting a person's name

Tags: strings, formatting, typescript

I need to take a user's name and format it 'lastName, firstName middleName'. If firstName and middleName are not present then the comma should not be included with lastName. Below is what I came up with and I'm wondering if there are ways I can make this better.

The code was adapted from another function written by a senior developer at my company. I'm trying to expand my way of problem-solving for conditional situations.

```
export function getLastNameFirstNameFullUserName(
  user: { firstName?: string; lastName?: string; middleName?: string },
  includeMiddleName = false,
): string {
  const { firstName, lastName, middleName } = user;

  const userNameArray: string[] = [];

  if (isNotEmptyString(lastName)) {
    useLastNameWithComma(firstName, includeMiddleName, middleName)
      ? userNameArray.push(`${lastName},`)
      : userNameArray.push(`${lastName}`);
  }

  isNotEmptyString(firstName) && userNameArray.push(`${firstName}`);

  includeMiddleName && isNotEmptyString(middleName) && userNameArray.push(`${middleName}`);

  return userNameArray.join(' ');
}

function useLastNameWithComma(firstName: string, includeMiddleName: boolean, middleName?: string): boolean {
  if (isNotEmptyString(firstName)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (includeMiddleName && isNotEmptyString(middleName)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

export function isNotEmptyString(item: string | null | undefined): boolean {
  return !['', null, undefined].includes(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution I ended up using with the help of a coworker and the answer above.

- Using if-statements with normal truthy checks removes the need to cast the optional parameters to string.
- Adding the last name at the end allowed me to remove the helper function that determines if a comma needs to be added.

  - Instead, we can just check that the array has an item already (first or middle name pushed) to know if we need to include the comma with the last name.
  - Then we can use `unshift` to add it to the front of the array.

I think this is a marked improvement in readability and reducing lines compared to the first version.

```
export function getLastNameFirstNameFullUserName(
  user: { firstName?: string; lastName?: string; middleName?: string },
  includeMiddleName = false,
): string {
  const { firstName, lastName, middleName } = user;

  const userNameArray: string[] = [];

  if (firstName) { 
    userNameArray.push(firstName); 
  }

  if (includeMiddleName && middleName) { 
    userNameArray.push(middleName); 
  }

  if (lastName) {
    const formattedLastName: string = userNameArray.length > 0 ? `${lastName},` : lastName;

    userNameArray.unshift(formattedLastName);
  }

  return userNameArray.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ideas to consider:

- Write "if" statements as normal `if` statements, ie. `if (isNotEmptyString(first))` instead of `isNotEmptyString(first) &&`
- Instead of the `isNotEmptyString` function, consider using the normal "truthy" value of strings. You can then more concisely write `if (first) userNameArray.push(first)`. You may need to write it as `!!first` or `Boolean(first)` for typescript. Also, I'm not a fan of using "not" in function names, as it can easily lead to double negatives.
- Remove unneeded string interpolation, like `${firstName}`, which is just `firstName`.

Some more stylistic ideas:

- Remove the word "Name" within variable names throughout. It makes the code bulkier with little benefit. I'd probably shorten the other variables too, without obfuscating anything. With less bulk, things are often easier to parse through.
- Rely on the result of evaluations to give you boolean values, instead of explicitly returning the constants `true` or `false`. For example, you can write `useLastNameWithComma` as:

```
function useLastNameWithComma(firstName: string, 
                              includeMiddleName: boolean, 
                              middleName?: string): boolean {
  return !!firstName || (includeMiddleName && !!middleName)
}
```

To me, this is easier to understand the logic when it's in one line, but not everyone would agree.

- Consider scoping `useLastNameWithComma` into the function you're writing, and then you don't have to pass all the variables and there's not as much to follow. It will just encapsulate the logic in a nice, named place.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
* I agree with the if statements rather than `boolean &&`. This was something adapted from my senior's code but is a weird style choice.
* `isNotEmptyString` was also a utility he made as he prefers very declarative approaches. I'm more partial to the normal truthy way you describe.
* String interpolation was needed because the compiler wasn't eliminating the `undefined` type, but with your method this is unneeded.
* Using "name" is required here because it's used in other places in the system. This matches our system design but I see your point